# Can I make a non-genericised implementation of a genericised Java interface?

Tags: java, generics

I've made an interface `ResponseEvaluator<T>` which is responsible for working out if an `HttpResponse<T>` is a success or not. (I've got to expand some code so it can use one of those irritating APIs which will return a 200 even if the operation has failed, and you can only tell it's gone wrong by looking at the error code in the body.) But I want to make an implementation that just looks at the status code, for use with APIs which will return a 4xx or 5xx if things have gone wrong. This implementation doesn't need to be genericized, it doesn't care what's in the body of the HttpResponse because it can just read the status code.

I tried doing

```
public class HttpCodeResponseEvaluator implements ResponseEvaluator<?>
```

but that isn't compiling because it doesn't like the wildcard. I could make it `HttpCodeResponseEvaluator<T>` and have a separate one for String or InputStream but I think it ought to be more straightforward than that.

Added:
`ResponseEvaluator<T>` has one method:

`ResponseEvaluation test(HttpResponse<T> httpResponse);`

`ResponseEvaluation` is an enum instead of a boolean so that it can say whether a failure is retryable (because the code at the moment retries 5xx errors after a backoff but not 4xx errors).

It's used by a `RequestSenderWithBackoff<T>` which is the class that handles the actual sending and the exponential backoff retries. This class used to look at the status codes to see if the call had been successful, and pulling that logic out into a ResponseEvaluator is my way of trying to cope with having to do more complex logic for an API that returns 200s for a failure.

Comment: Maybe implementing `ResponseEvaluator<Object>`? I'm not sure that would work since I'm not sure where/how this will be used, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Can you show what methods `ResponseEvaluator` has?

Comment: Why parametrize `ResponseEvaluator` and not just the test method?

Comment: Thank-you for your comments. I worked through your question @michid and realised that I needed the parameterisation so that I could constrain the RequestSenderWithBackoff to have the correct type of ResponseEvaluator...

Comment: ...So then I realised I could do as @Federico klez Culloca suggests and have a ResponseEvaluator of Object, as long as I made the RequestSenderWithBackoff of T take a ResponseEvaluator of ? super T. So I have done that, and it's all OK. Thanks everyone!